# Access Azure Data Explorer from App Service

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have an app service deployed to Azure

It has the following code

```
kcsb = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(Cluster, Database);

where
  Cluster = kusto Data Explorer cluster
  Database = database within the data explorer
```

I have turned on the system assigned identity of the app service and given it viewer access to the database

When I try and invoke the service I get the following

Internal Server Error - Unauthorized (): Authorization has been denied for this request.. This normally represents a permanent error, and retrying is unlikely to help.
Please provide the following information when contacting the Kusto team @ https://aka.ms/kustosupport :
DataSource='https://test1cluster.australiasoutheast.kusto.windows.net/v1/rest/query',

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correction, Azure Data Explorer supports app service managed identities using the **WithAadManagedIdentity()** method. Here is an example based on your code above

```
new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(Cluster, Database).WithAadManagedIdentity(identityName);
```

identityName should be the name of your user-assigned identity or "system" for system-assigned identity

I apologize but the docs are not updates yet, they will be updated in the next few days.

Comment: Didn't know it wasn't supported yet.  Cheers